# How to validate a time in “YYYY: MM: DD HH:MM:SS” format in c++?

Tags: validation, date, c++11, boost

I want to validate a time given in string format as “YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS” and want to check which is latest date.

I can able to convert given string into seconds and compare them as follows.

```
std::string dateStr1 = "2016-06-31 02:00:58"; // June 31 2016 does not exist
std::string dateStr2 = "02:00:00";

std::istringstream date_s(dateStr1);
struct tm date_c;
date_s >> std::get_time( &date_c, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" );
std::time_t seconds1 = std::mktime( & date_c );

std::istringstream date_s2( "2001-10-01 02:10:00" );
struct tm date_c2;
date_s2 >> std::get_time( &date_c2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" );
std::time_t seconds2 = std::mktime( & date_c2 );

if(seconds1 > seconds2){  
    cout<<" Seconds1 is greater "<<seconds1<<endl;
}else{
    cout<<" Seconds2 is greater "<<seconds2<<endl;
}
```

Answer: `Seconds1 is greater 1467334858`

Problem: this method converts a date that doesn’t exist. 
( the date given in dateStr1 is doesn’t exist but mktime() makes time for this date. )

How to check whether a date exist or not?

Comment: This is non-trivial due to timezone changes and leap seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [cppreference documentation of mktime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime):

> If the conversion is successful, the time object is modified. All
>   fields of time are updated to fit their proper ranges. time->tm_wday
>   and time->tm_yday are recalculated using information available in
>   other fields.

You can use this to check if the date was valid or not. If it was invalid, the `tm` struct will be modified by `mktime`:

```
std::string dateStr1 = "2016-06-31 02:00:58"; // June 31 2016 does not exist
std::string dateStr2 = "02:00:00";

std::istringstream date_s(dateStr1);
struct tm date_c, date_c_cmp;
date_s >> std::get_time( &date_c, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" );
date_c_cmp = date_c;  // store original  to compare later
std::time_t seconds1 = std::mktime( & date_c );
if(date_c.tm_year != date_c_cmp.tm_year  // compare with original
        || date_c.tm_mon != date_c_cmp.tm_mon
        || date_c.tm_mday != date_c_cmp.tm_mday
        || date_c.tm_hour != date_c_cmp.tm_hour
        || date_c.tm_min != date_c_cmp.tm_min
        || date_c.tm_sec != date_c_cmp.tm_sec)
    std::cout << "invalid" << std::endl;

std::istringstream date_s2( "2001-10-01 02:10:00" );
struct tm date_c2;
date_s2 >> std::get_time( &date_c2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" );
std::time_t seconds2 = std::mktime( & date_c2 );

if(seconds1 > seconds2){  
    std::cout<<" Seconds1 is greater "<<seconds1<<std::endl;
}else{
    std::cout<<" Seconds2 is greater "<<seconds2<<std::endl;
}
```